# Postgres function returning wrong datatype

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to install ubuntuone on a ubuntu server 15.04 and it seems there are a few things that aren't working anymore.

The main problem I have is a query that is failing. Here is how it looks like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION activity() RETURNS SETOF pg_stat_activity
    LANGUAGE sql SECURITY DEFINER
    SET search_path TO public
    AS $$
    SELECT
        datid, datname, pid, usesysid, usename,
        application_name, client_addr, client_hostname, client_port,
        backend_start, xact_start, query_start, waiting,
        CASE
            WHEN query LIKE '<IDLE>%'
                OR query LIKE 'autovacuum:%'
                THEN query
            ELSE
                '<HIDDEN>'
        END AS current_query
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity;
$$;
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return pg_stat_activity
DETAIL:  Final statement returns boolean instead of timestamp with time zone at column 13.
CONTEXT:  SQL function "activity"
```

I understand the error, but I don't know how it is returning a bool. I ran the same query manually and still get the same error. Note that I am not too familiar with postgres so please be detailed.

What part of the query is returning a bool? or is the query correct at all?

Note the application was written for postgresql-9.1 but I am running 9.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning a row compatible with the layout of [`pg_stat_activity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW).  The layout of `pg_stat_activity` is:

```
> \d pg_stat_activity ;
           View "pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity"
      Column      |           Type           | Modifiers 
------------------+--------------------------+-----------
 datid            | oid                      | 
 datname          | name                     | 
 pid              | integer                  | 
 usesysid         | oid                      | 
 usename          | name                     | 
 application_name | text                     | 
 client_addr      | inet                     | 
 client_hostname  | text                     | 
 client_port      | integer                  | 
 backend_start    | timestamp with time zone | 
 xact_start       | timestamp with time zone | 
 query_start      | timestamp with time zone | 
 state_change     | timestamp with time zone | 
 waiting          | boolean                  | 
 state            | text                     | 
 backend_xid      | xid                      | 
 backend_xmin     | xid                      | 
 query            | text                     |
```

Your query is producing columns correctly up to and including `query_start`.  But then you are returning a boolean (`waiting`) in the column that should be `state_change`, a timezone.

Correct your query to include the extra columns in the correct order (ie `state_change`, `waiting`, `state`, `backend_xid`, `backend_xmin`, `query`)

Comment: Thank you so much, now I finally understand clearly the problem. I will add your response to the bugfix commit.

Comment: The view has been changed in versions 9.2 and 9.3. See it [in the documentation v.9.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW)